# PHP Fluent Getters. Get the value of a specific method in a chain of functions

Tags: php

could you help me with a question I have? I happen to be trying to make use of fluent getters to get different results in a chain method call. Suppose we have a hypothetical class `A`:

```
<?php

class A
{
    public $array = [
        'key_1' => 'Key 1',
        'key_2' => 'Key 2',
    ];

    public function methodA()
    {
        // Should return the property $array as array
    }

    public function methodB()
    {
        // Should return and array with keys of the property $array
    }

    public function asJson()
    {
        // It must return the value of any of the previous methods that is called in JSON format.
    }
}
```

And I would like that depending on whether I call some method without chaining the `asJson` method at the end, it returns the value of that method. My expected results would be as follows.

```
class B
{
    public function test()
    {
        $class = new A();

        var_dump($class->methodA());

        /**
        array:2 [
          "key_1" => "Key 1"
          "key_2" => "Key 2"
        ]
        */

        var_dump($class->methodB());

        /**
        array:2 [
          "0" => "key_1"
          "1" => "key_2"
        ]
        */

        var_dump($class->methodA()->asJson());

        /**
         "{
           "key_1":"Key 1",
           "key_2":"Key 2"
          }"
        */

        var_dump($class->methodB()->asJson());

        /**
         "[
           "key_1",
           "key_2"
          ]"
        */
    }
}
```

I don't know if I should use `ReflectionClass` here or is there an elegant way to get the result I expect. Thank you very much

Comment: What you exactly need? you want to ```var_dump()``` or ```echo()``` or assign to variable ?

Comment: Is there any problem if the function calling sequence will be little bit different, like ```$class->asJson()->methodA()``` ?

Comment: @AnisurRahman I only need each method to return as value the example I put above. I would like it to follow the order it showed ... like "```methodA ()->asJson ()```", anyway, could you show me any solution you have in mind?

Comment: yes i have, but it would be like ```asJson ()->methodA ()``` or ```methodA ()->asJson ()->get()``` and ```methodA ()->get()```